I am trying to build a logistic regression model
I have a time series data of which a family have spent money on different products. Each product is allocated to a category ( it can be a two level category path ) for eg- (Food  > Chicken) or (Personal Care > Make up) . Data is weekly. Every week family have a chance of winning a reward based on the spends they have. So i am trying this problem like a classification problem. Given a set of data which week family will receive a reward. Figuring out different features from the weekly spend data, like total number of spends, total number of spends less than 10, 20, 100 etc. sum of top 100 spends in a particular category, sum of top 100 spends in a parent category ( for eg. Food), number of category family is spending etc.
I would like to include the notion of category path to the feature data set. For eg. I am assuming spending in a category path is not same as in another one. Or sometimes the spending pattern in a particular category path could be the reason for reward not because of all the category path spends of the family.
How I can do that ? The number of category paths are finite like less than 100 and top level category paths are less than 10.
How to bring the category path info into the dataset and train a logistic regression model or  doing this is a bad idea bringing in the category path ?
